# When I use fetch my .then code isn't working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch

So I am trying to redirect after I am deleting the page, it get's deleted from the database but it doesn't redirect me to my homepage. It worked fine when I was using json-server locally, but when I started using Mongoose it wasn't working properly and wasn't redirecting.

The code inside `.then` isn't working, I tried console.log inside the `.then` but it didn't log

I am using mongoose as my database

Here is my entire component:

```js
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import useFetch from "../useFetch";
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";
import moment from "moment";

import profile_image from "../images/picture.jpg";

const BlogDetails = () => {

    let blogDate = moment().format('D MMM YYYY');
    const { id } = useParams();
    const { data: blog, isPending, errorMsg } = useFetch("http://localhost:5000/postsdata/" + id);
    const history = useHistory()

    const handleDelete = () => {
        fetch('http://localhost:5000/postsdata/' + blog._id, { method: 'DELETE' })
            .then(() => {
                history.push('/');
            })
            .catch((err) => console.log(err))
    }

  return (
    <div className="blog-details">
      <div className="top-profile">
        <div className="top-profile-picture">
          <img src={profile_image} alt="profile-pic-top" />
        </div>
        <div className="top-profile-name">
          <p>Vishwajeet Deshmukh</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      {isPending && <div>Loading...</div>}
      {errorMsg && <div>{errorMsg}</div>}
          {blog && (
        <article className="blog-main-content" >
          <div className="main-content-header">
            <div className="content-title-date">
              <h2 className="blogdetails-title">{blog.title}</h2>
              <p className="blogdetails-date">{blogDate}</p>
            </div>
            <div className="content-image">
                <img src={blog.imgsrc} alt="" />
            </div>
          </div>

          <div className="blogdetails-body"><p>{`${blog.postBody}`}</p></div>
          <button className="blogdetails-delete" onClick={handleDelete}>Delete Me</button>
        </article>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

export default BlogDetails;
```

Here is my `router.js` which handles my delete

```js
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const { Posts } = require("./models");

//<----------------------------------- CRUD OPERATIONS ------------------------------------------>

router.get("/", () => {
    console.log("Server Connected");
})

//<---------------------------- Get Posts from Database ---------------------------->

router.get("/postsdata", (req, res) => {
    
    Posts.find((err, data) => {
        if (err) {
            res.status(500).send(err);
        } else {
            res.status(201).send(data);
        }
        return null;
    })
})

//<------------- Get Specific Posts from Database --------------->

router.get("/postsdata/:_id", (req, res) => {
    const id = req.params._id;
        Posts.findById(id, (err, data) => {
            if (err) {
                res.status(500).send(err);
                throw new Error(err)
            } else {
                res.status(201).send(data);
            }
            return data;
        })
})

//<---------------------------- Post On the Posts Database ---------------------------->
router.post("/postsdata", (req, res) => {
    
    const db = req.body;
    Posts.create(db, err => {
        if (!err) {
            console.log("Posted on Server");
        } else {
            throw new Error(err)
        }
        return null
    })
})

//<---------------------------- Delete Posts from Database ---------------------------->
router.delete("/postsdata/:id", (req, res) => {
    const id = req.params._id
    Posts.deleteOne(id, (err, data) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            throw new Error(err)
        } else {
            console.log(data);
        }
        return null
    })
})

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: `useHistory` must be inside a component? Is it inside a component?

Comment: Not enough info here to solve. Please post your entire React component. A screenshot of the Network Request panel would also be good.

Comment: @evolutionxbox It is inside a component

Comment: @TJBlackman I have edited the question and added the entire code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after deleting the postdata, send a response from the API.

```
    router.delete("/postsdata/:id", (req, res) => {
    const id = req.params._id

    Posts.deleteOne(id, (err, data) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            throw new Error(err)
        } else {
            return res.status(200).json({status: 'success'}); // try with this
        }
        return null
    })
    })
```

Comment: Happy to help 

Answer (score 0):

Hello try it with async/await sayntax

```js
const handleDelete = async () => {
    await fetch('http://localhost:5000/postsdata/' + blog._id, { method: 'DELETE' });
    history.push('/');  
}
```

Comment: Nope didn't work